# Vector identity proof

Tags: calculus

I am told that $\nabla\times(\nabla\times A)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot A)-\triangle A$.

I'm then asked to use this to show that $\nabla\times(\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))=-\triangle(\nabla\times A).$

So \begin{align*}\nabla\times(\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))
&=\nabla\times(\nabla(\nabla\cdot A)-\triangle A)\\
&=\nabla\times(\nabla(\nabla\cdot A)-\nabla\cdot\nabla A))\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\partial_k\partial_mA_m-\partial_k\partial_kA)
\end{align*}

It doesn't look like this is taking me anywhere though. What should I be doing?

Comment: You are probably asked to use other formulas for the cross product that you already have, instead of using the definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the inner $\nabla \times A$ term and calculate from the 'outside'. Then using the stated identity:
$$ \nabla\times (\nabla \times (\nabla\times A)) =\nabla (\nabla \cdot (\nabla\times A)) - \Delta (\nabla \times A) =- \Delta (\nabla \times A)  $$
(in the first term one has $\nabla \cdot (\nabla\times A)=0$ ).

Comment: ... or keep $\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec A$ and note that $\nabla \times \nabla \Phi=0$ and $\nabla \times \nabla^2 \vec A=\nabla^2 \nabla \times \vec A$.

Comment: @H. H. Rugh I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. Could you explain further?

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS:**

$$\nabla \times \nabla \Phi=0$$

and

$$\nabla \times \nabla^2 \vec A=\nabla^2 \nabla \times  \vec A$$